# SQL putting an AND within an OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a condition based on the following:

```
where new.Number <> old.Number
and new.Number is not null
```

this selects rows that have a changed 'number' so long as the 'new number' is not blank

I want to add another condition that can be used as the other side of an 'OR' but am confused as how to do this, my brain says:

```
where (((new.Number <> old.Number) and new.Number is not null) or (new condition))
```

So we would select rows that pass the previous conditions OR pass the new condition but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your logic seems correct for what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe you should show us what **new condition** stands for

Comment: this will do: where (new.Number <> old.Number and new.Number is not null) or (new condition)

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, your logic is correct except that the parenthesis covering the entire `WHERE` clause is useless. Provide us your code with the new condition, the problem may probably be there.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin . . . Actually all the parentheses are useless, according to SQL precedence rules.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good remark! I always use parentheses to make the query more readable and with this approach every parentheses make sens except the mentioned one. But in a technical point of view you're totally right.

Comment: my new condition is "doc.type is not null" so if we have the document we dont need the number to have been updated ( i previously had "left join (select reference, type from documents where type in(13,14)) doc on new.reference = doc.reference" so any without the documents would have doc.type as null)

Comment: I think you just need: `(old.number is null and new.number is not null) OR (new.number <> old.number) OR (doc.type is not null)`

Answer (score 2):

**Revised Answer**

Assuming that you **DO** want to include results that involve NULL you have two options:

**Option 1**

Use the **`OR`** clause intelligently:

```
WHERE old.Number IS NULL OR old.Number <> new.Number
```

This matches if:

1. Old number is NULL
2. Or both numbers are not NULL and different

This does not match in all other cases including:

1. Old number is not NULL
2. And new number is NULL or both numbers are same

**Option 2**

Use [**`ISNULL`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function to compare NULL values like this:

```
WHERE ISNULL(new.Number, -1) <> ISNULL(old.number, -1)
```

This matches if:

1. Both numbers are different (e.g. `1 <> 2`)
2. Or one of the numbers is NULL (e.g. `1 <> NULL` and `NULL <> 2`)

This does not match if:

1. Both numbers are same (e.g. `1 <> 1`)
2. Or both numbers are NULL (e.g. `NULL <> NULL`)

---

In any case, `(` and `)` could be used when you mix AND and OR clauses.

Comment: Good call! If new.Number would be equal to NULL, it would not match old.Number anyway (because NULL != NULL)

Comment: This appears to be working, i'm double checking through the results now to make sure. Thanks a bundle :)

Comment: @Salman I've just had a thought, would this exclude rows where old.number is null and new.number is null? Because NULL != NULL ?

Comment: If either number is null then row will be excluded. I assumed you want them excluded because of the `IS NOT NULL` clause.

Comment: @Salman I'm going to have to rethink this whole clause to be honest. Basically I wanted to get rows where a new number has been entered (and not just removed if there was one before... new. is the 'current' details table old. is the history table for the details) or we have the document.

So I was aiming for: (old.number is null and new.number is not null) or (old.number is not null and new.number <> old.number and new.number is not null) or(doc.type is not null)

Comment: The [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function is an option. See revised answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite the first condition into something like WHERE new.Number NOT IN (null, old.Number) to have it as a single expression, which could make the 'OR' easier.

Also, are you absolutely sure that the function is correct without the new condition?
For us there is no way of checking, because there is no context about the tables you select.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...
WHERE (new.Number <> old.Number AND new.Number IS NOT NULL) OR (new condition)

Answer (score 0):

As was said, you can consolidate the original condition to remove the `is not null`. However, I still prefer to be explicit about the intent of this, and therefore I prefer this pattern:

```
coalesce(new.Number, old.Number) <> old.Number
```

This makes it clearer for future maintainers that you had explicitly considered what you wanted to do with NULL values, and it still condenses you down to one expression that you can easily combine with ar `OR`.

But in the future, if you have more complex conditions that won't consolidate, just remember your parentheses:

```
WHERE ( new.Number <> old.Number and new.Number is not null )
     OR ( other condition )
```